# Dictionary/Flashcard problem. Starting with the value rather than the key

Tags: python

I want to try this flashcard idea to try and learn keywords and their meanings for an upcoming test. I want create a dictionary on python which I can use to help with this. The idea is that the definition is shown to me and then I have to guess the word that has been defined. I have shown below how to do it where the key is shown first then the value but I want it to do the opposite but can't figure out how to implement this. (The glossary in the code below refers to my dictionary)
Any help would be appreciated.

```
def show_flashcard():
    """ Show a random key and ask me
        to define it. Show the definition
        when the user presses return.    
    """
    random_key = choice(list(glossary))
    print('Define: ', random_key)
    input('Press return to see the definition')
    print(glossary[random_key])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
def show_flashcard():
    """ Show a random definition and ask me
        the key. Show the key
        when the user presses return.    
    """
    random_key, random_def = choice(list(glossary.items()))
    print('Define: ', random_def)
    input('Press return to see the key')
    print(random_key)
```

Comment: Thank you rusu_ro1 and Taxel for the help.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, shouldn't this suffice?

```
print('Define: ', glossary[random_key])
input('Press return to see the definition')
print(random_key)
```

Essentially just switch the question and the answer.